# ffmpeg "Requested output format 'decklink is not a suitable format'"

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to play a video using ffmpeg and decklink.
I compiled ffmpeg from ffmpeg repo.
I am working in ubuntu 16.04 lts.

Here is my command :

```
./ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -threads 0 -re -i ./sample_1080_50i.ts -bufsize 1M -vf yadif -format_code Hi50 -f decklink -preroll 0.7 -pix_fmt uyvy422 'DeckLink Studio 4K'
```

The result is :

```
ffmpeg version N-89978-gcb97400 Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.1.1 (Ubuntu 5.1.0-0ubuntu11~10.04.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/home/sarslan/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags='-I/home/sarslan/ffmpeg_build/include -I/home/sarslan/ffmpeg_sources/Blackmagic_DeckLink_SDK_10.9.5/Linux/include' --extra-ldflags=-L/home/sarslan/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/sarslan/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-static --disable-shared --enable-decklink --enable-ffplay
  libavutil      56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
  libavcodec     58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavdevice    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavfilter     7. 11.101 /  7. 11.101
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, mpegts, from './sample_1080_50i.ts':
  Duration: 00:05:00.08, start: 1.437333, bitrate: 4675 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
    Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(top first), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x101](eng): Audio: aac (LC) ([15][0][0][0] / 0x000F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 123 kb/s
[NULL @ 0xb2ed180] Requested output format 'decklink' is not a suitable output format
DeckLink Studio 4K: Invalid argument
```

I think, this error is weird.
I enabled decklink support with --enable-decklink, and I also check ffmpeg documentation decklink part.'decklink' is used with -f option in every example.

Then I check the command line, and I can't find any error with the command.
Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Thanks and best regards,

Comment: What's the output of `ffmpeg -muxers -v 0 | grep decklink`?

Comment: Output is : E decklink        Blackmagic DeckLink output @Mulvya. Do you have any advice ?

Comment: This looks to be due to a new API which broke the assignment of output formats. It has just been reverted. So, either build it from latest source, or switch to a pre-Feb-6 build.

Comment: Okay, I build ffmpeg from latest source, I can play x264 encoded 1080i50 video with decklink, but I can not play x265 encoded 1080i50 video. Error is `[decklink @ 0xb1ee8a0] Trying to find mode for frame size 1920x540, frame timing 1/50, field order 1, direction 1, mode number 0, format code (unset)
[decklink @ 0xb1ee8a0] Unsupported video size, framerate or field order! Check available formats with -list_formats 1.
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Input/output error
Error initializing output stream 0:1 --`
Can you have any advice ?

Comment: Also video is 1920x1080i50, but ffmpeg says frame size 1920x540. Is it bug or do I have to add any option to command ? @Mulvya

Comment: Sounds like the HEVC bitstream is interlaced and stored as half-pictures, Process it with [tinterlace](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#tinterlace) filter and check.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, I want to double the height of the video, so first I tried tinterlace option with pad mode with following command : `ffmpeg -i 20180130102728_0_0.ts -vf "tinterlace=pad" -f mpegts -pix_fmt yuv420p test1.ts` but with this command, output video quality is so bad. From documentation, "pad alternate lines with black". I think the quality problem caused by this situation. @Mulvya

Comment: Also I tried to use mergex2 mode for tinterlace option. I tried to run `ffmpeg -i 20180130102728_0_0.ts -vf "tinterlace=mergex2" -f mpegts -pix_fmt yuv420p test1.ts` command, but following error comes `[tinterlace @ 0x9cf8e0] [Eval @ 0x7ffdf58d0f20] Undefined constant or missing '(' in 'mergex2'
[tinterlace @ 0x9cf8e0] Unable to parse option value "mergex2"` . Then I also tried `ffmpeg -i 20180130102728_0_0.ts -vf "tinterlace=7" -f mpegts -pix_fmt yuv420p test1.ts` command for mergex2 mode. But following error occured. `Value 7.000000 for parameter 'mode' out of range [0 - 6]`

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for using the mergex2 mode for tinterlace option. @Mulvya

Comment: *but with this command, output video quality is so bad.* --> more likely because MPEG-TS defaults to MPEG-2 codec with 200 kbps bitrate. Add `-c:v libx264` and check.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mulvya. tinterlace filter solved my problem. Actually my problem is related to decklink output. When I try to use this filter with decklink, problem is solved. My example command is like this : ffmpeg -err_detect ignore_err -threads 0 -re -i ./20180212113531_0_0_1080i50.ts -bufsize 1M -vf "tinterlace=merge" -format_code Hi50 -f decklink -preroll 0.7 -pix_fmt uyvy422 'DeckLink Quad (2)'. Thanks again :)